# Button to check youtube subscription status for my Channel

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to create a button. When someone clicks it will check the status of the user for a youtube channel subscription. I you want to check the subscription status of the user who is clicking the button for my youtube channel.

Using following JS Code:

```
function checkSubscriptionStatus() {
  var channelID = 'your_channel_id';
  var APIKey = 'your_api_key';
  
  // Get user's Google account ID from YouTube API
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
      mine: true,
      part: 'id'
    }).then(function(response) {
      var userID = response.result.items[0].id;

      // Use the YouTube Data API to retrieve subscription status
      var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions';
      url += '?part=status&channelId=' + channelID + '&subscriberId=' + userID + '&key=' + APIKey;

      // Send API request
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          // Check if the user is subscribed
          var isSubscribed = data.items[0].status.subscribed;
          if (isSubscribed) {
            // User is subscribed, show message or do something else
            console.log('User is subscribed');
          } else {
            // User is not subscribed, show message or do something else
            console.log('User is not subscribed');
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error checking subscription status', error);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

But I am getting following error in my console:

```
error loading GAPI client for API
```

Note: I have already included following code in my header file as I adding this button in a WordPress website

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'],
    });
  }
  gapi.load('client', initClient);
</script>
```

Would love to have some help from the community.

Comment: You shouldn't add your API key to client side javascript, since anyone could have access to it. Instead add to the server side PHP.

Comment: Good point I have added restrictions to API for my website only.